# Error to execute QEMU on Eclipse with STM32F429

Tags: stm32, eclipse

I follow this tutorial: https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/tutorials/blinky-arm/

And, installed openOCD, QEMU, Packs... all that is need. But when I start the Debug the follow error occurs:
[image]

He compiles succesfully, but when the starts this crash happens... And prorgram not execute.

Error:

```
PRIGROUP unimplemented
assert_param() failed: file "../system/src/stm32f4-hal/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.c", line 470
abort(), exiting..
```

Also, I noticed that "Play Button" is not available, but "Pause"
 and "Stop" is.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is attempting to use functionality unsupported by the simulator.

The message tells you at exactly which line of which source file the offending attempt is made.

You will have to avoid this, or pursue it with the authors of the board simulator.

Generally speaking, simulating things like this is a bit unusual - it can be fun, but most would test on the real hardware, possible with an SWD debugger (which is already on that board) connected.

Comment: I have the board, but I wants use the simulator. How I can what functionality I need install ? Or how I know which functionality available?

Comment: If you have a board I do not understand what is the point of the emulation. Waste of time and energy